# Code inside Kotlin's GlobalScope (Coroutine) is not working properly

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm trying to make visualizer of quicksort algorithm, the functionality of alogrithm is fine but when i put the code in GlobalScope so that i can use delay to visulize things, the algorithm behaves differently.
Here are my functions....

```
//Quick Sort Part
private suspend fun partition(arr: MutableList<Button>, low: Int, high: Int): Int {
    //If I comment this job, and run the code the algorithm works
    val job2 = GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        var low = low
        var high = high
        var pivot = arr[(low + high) / 2].layoutParams.height
       
        while (low <= high) {
            Log.d(TAG, "partition: $low  $high")
            while (arr[low].layoutParams.height < pivot) {
                low++
            }
            while (arr[high].layoutParams.height > pivot) {
                high--
            }

            if (low <= high) {
                val temp = arr[low].layoutParams.height
                arr[low].layoutParams.height = arr[high].layoutParams.height
                arr[high].layoutParams.height = temp
                root_layout.requestLayout()
                low++
                high--
            }
        }
    }
    job2.join()
    return low
}


private fun quickSort(arr: MutableList<Button>, low: Int, high: Int) {
    val job1 = GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        val pi = partition(arr, low, high)
        if (low < pi - 1) {
            quickSort(arr, low, pi - 1)
        }
        if (pi < high) {
            quickSort(arr, pi, high)
        }
    }

}
```

[image: This is when I'm using coroutine]

This is the result of that function, and if i don't use coroutine, this works fine, all the bars gets sorted in increasing order..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have defined the low and high variables inside the launch scope, and updating it there but still returning the variable which was received as parameter.

Define it in the outerscope:

```kotlin
var low = low  // define the variable in the outer scope
val job2 = GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {  // ...
```

But shadowing isn't the best way (it is error prone as it tricked you), just name it something else for simplicity.

*Tip: Use of Main thread is usually for less CPU intensive tasks and should be used mainly for displaying stuffs and updating UI. For computational tasks feel free to use the Dispatchers.Default!*

Also using Jobs for doing tasks and joining them isn't that optimized than [withContext](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/with-context.html) which is intended for returning the result from another Dispatching thread easily, use it instead!

```kotlin
private suspend fun partition(arr: MutableList<Button>, low: Int, high: Int): Int {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
        var low = low
        var high = high
        var pivot = arr[(low + high) / 2].layoutParams.height
       
        while (low <= high) {
            Log.d(TAG, "partition: $low  $high")
            while (arr[low].layoutParams.height < pivot) {
                low++
            }
            while (arr[high].layoutParams.height > pivot) {
                high--
            }

            if (low <= high) {
                val temp = arr[low].layoutParams.height
                arr[low].layoutParams.height = arr[high].layoutParams.height
                arr[high].layoutParams.height = temp
                root_layout.requestLayout()
                low++
                high--
            }
        }
        low  //^withContext
    }
}
```